# Read line by line in C but incorrect length

Tags: c

My code is read a string in line from file and print it and its length on screen. But the length is incorrect (bigger than 1).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    FILE * file;
    file= fopen("data.txt","r");
    char* singleLine;
    singleLine = (char *) malloc(150* sizeof(char *));

    if(file){
        while(!feof(file)){
            fgets(singleLine,150, file);
            puts(singleLine);
            printf("length: %ld\n",strlen(singleLine));
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you add the content of the file to your question as well. Also post the output if possible.

Comment: Side note: `fclose(file);` should be within the `if` clause. And it's `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, so you should use the `%zu` format specifier.

Comment: `singleLine = (char *) malloc(150* sizeof(char *))` you are allocating 150 *pointers* here.

Comment: data.txt look like 
cat
dog 
human
etc...

Comment: @ĐặngTrung please [edit] your question and show the data.txt file _there_. In comments it doesn't make much sense as you cannot put newlines in comments

Comment: Do you mean "bigger than 1" or "bigger _by_ 1"?  If it is bigger by 1, then the extra byte is the newline that `fgets()` keeps.  If you mean bigger than 1, then if there's more than a newline on the line, you'll get a length that's bigger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

> `fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)` reads in at most `size-1` characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.
>   Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**.  A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

If the length of a line is less than 149 bytes, and it is not the end of file, then the **newline** will be read to the buf. Thus the return value of strlen will include the **newline**.

Plus: If your just need 150 characters buffer, instead of `malloc(150* sizeof(char *))`, `malloc(sizeof(char) * 150)` might be more reasonable.

There is no need to cast the result of malloc. For detail please go this question [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Thank you but how can i fix it?

Comment: Implement a strlen which do not count newline, or remove the newline from the buffer after a successful call of `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the newline character that results in the extra length in the following manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char* singleLine;

    FILE * file = fopen("data.txt","r");

    singleLine = (char *) malloc(150* sizeof(char));

    if(file)
    {
        char *p = NULL;

        while(fgets(singleLine, 150, file) != NULL) //giving the length here directly as 150 is important, because using sizeof() or strlen() only reads the 1st 3 characters(which is the size of char * on my platform) of the string.
        {
            p = strstr(singleLine,"\n");

            if(p)
            {
                *p = '\0';
            }
            printf("%s\n", singleLine);

            printf("length: %ld\n",strlen(singleLine));
        }
        if (feof(file))
        {
            fclose(file);   
        }
        else
        {
            printf("some other error occured");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("inside else\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `p` points to the newline, you can use `if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';` without needing to use `strlen()`.  And [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: `while (fgets(singleLine, 150, file) != 0)` (replaces loop condition and line after it).  You should normally test the result of the actual I/O operation — `fgets()`, `getchar()`, `scanf()`, whatever.  Also, it is often effective to use `singleLine[strcspn(singleLine, "\n")] = '\0';` to eliminate the newline.